# VB reads from excel file in a fast way

Tags: vb.net, excel, algorithm, cell

I got this problem when I start my projeect :

I'm supposed to write VB program which read and write data from every single cell from a excel file, my excel file contains about 2000 rows and 25 cols, and this number will vary from time to time (it's just a employ record file which will be more less from time to time but not change in a big scale) but the reading and searching time cause the program to be lag, usually searching a item inside costs more then 3 seconds and loading all the data into the program will cause more then 30 secs, I haven't wrote the writing-into-file part but i believe it will cost more time.

In my program I use for loop to go through all cells and same for searching , is there a faster way for processing this ?

Comment: Use a variant array for the read and write.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way try to use find method

```
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

this will set the range to aCell, strSearch is the string that your looking to search.

Comment: I got this in my code, I was searching in a specific col to look for an item but it's still slow, the excel file is local, and only 2000 records in a col